# Swiper pagination not working properly in desktop and mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper.js

The pagination appears mixed up in the text and i would wish that it appears below the text as a stand alone item to be visibly seen.

Another thing is that when in mobile view the hamburger when open displays behind the slider and i want it to display in-front of the slider.

Html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1'>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="swiper.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.menu-toggle').click(function(){
                $('.site-nav').toggleClass('site-nav--open');
                $(this).toggleClass('open');
            })
        })
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="logo">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">SakaHapa</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <nav class="site-nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home site-nav--icon"></i>HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-question-circle-o site-nav--icon"></i>HOW IT WORKS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user-circle site-nav--icon"></i>PROFILE</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cart-plus site-nav--icon"></i>PURCHASES</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-eye site-nav--icon"></i>POPULAR</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope site-nav--icon"></i>CONTACT</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-power-off site-nav--icon"></i>Log Out</a></li>
            </ul> 
        </nav>
        <div class="menu-toggle">
            <div class="hamburger"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </header>


    <div class="container">
        <div class="swiper-container">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <div class="slide-text">
                        <h2>Slide man</h2>
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
                            Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, 
                            when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen 
                            book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic 
                            typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the 
                            release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop 
                            publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <div class="slide-text">
                        <h2>Mafans</h2>
                        <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable 
                            content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is 
                            that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 
                            'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop 
                            publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default 
                            model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in 
                            their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, 
                            sometimes on purpose.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</div>
            </div>
            <!-- Add Pagination -->
            <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
            </div> 

            <script type="text/javascript" src="swiper.min.js"></script>
            <!-- Initialize Swiper -->
            <script>
                var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
                    pagination: {
                        el: '.swiper-pagination',
                        clickable: true,
                        renderBullet: function (index, className) {
                            return '<span class="' + className + '">' + (index + 1) + '</span>';
                        },
                    },
                });
            </script>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body{
    background: #F0F8EA;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
.container{
    width: 95%;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
header{
    background: #E54B4B;
    color: #f8f4f4;
    padding: 1em 0;
    position: relative;
}
header::after{
    content: '';
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
.logo{
    float: left;
    font-size: 1.65em;
    margin: 0;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.logo ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.logo a{
    color: #f8f4f4;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.logo a:hover,
.logo a:focus{
    color: #464655;
}
.navbar-nav{
    outline: none;
    float: right;
}
.navbar-nav ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.navbar-nav a{
    color: #f8f4f4;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 130%;
    right: .75em;
}
.navbar-nav a:hover,
.navbar-nav a:focus{
    color: #464655;
}

.site-nav{
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    right: 0%;
    background: #464655;
    clip-path: circle(0px at top right);
    transition: clip-path ease-in-out 700ms;
    /* display: none; */
}
.site-nav--open{
    clip-path: circle(100%);
}
.site-nav ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.site-nav li{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #575766;
}
.site-nav li:last-child{
    border-bottom: none;
}
.site-nav a{
    color: #f8f4f4;
    display: block;
    padding: 1.5em 4.5em;    
    text-decoration: none;
}
.site-nav a:hover,
.site-nav a:focus{
    background: #E4B363;
    color: #464655;
}
.site-nav--icon{
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin-right: 1em;
    width: 0.7em;
    text-align: right;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,.4);
}
.menu-toggle{
    padding: 1em;
    position: absolute;
    top: .75em;
    right: .75em;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.hamburger,
.hamburger::before,
.hamburger::after{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    background: #f8f4f4;
    height: 3px;
    width: 1.95em;
    border-radius: 3px;
    transition: all ease-in-out 500ms;
}
.hamburger::before{
    transform: translateY(-7px);
}
.hamburger::after{
    transform: translateY(4px);
}
.open .hamburger{
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.open .hamburger::before{
    opacity: 0;
}
.open .hamburger::after{
    transform: translateY(-3px) rotate(-90deg);
}
@media (min-width: 1077px){
    .menu-toggle{
        display: none;
    }
    .site-nav{
        height: auto;
        position: relative;
        background: transparent;
        float: right;
        clip-path: initial;
    }
    .site-nav li{
        display: inline-block;
        border: none;
    }
    .site-nav a{
        padding: 0;
        margin-left: 1.2em;
        font-size: 1.15em;
        padding-top: 7px;
    }
    .site-nav a:hover,
    .site-nav a:focus{
        background: transparent;
    }
    .site-nav li .fa{
        display: none;   
    }
}


.content-section{
    background: #f8f4f4;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 500px;
    margin: auto;
    color: #131212;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    border: 2px solid rgb(15, 15, 15);
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  div.form-group{
    margin-top: -24px;
  }
  .btn{
    background: rgb(41, 159, 180);
  }
  h5{
      color: #ffff;
  }
  h6{
     color: #ffff; 
  }
  .register{
    background: #dbd7d7;
  }


html, body{
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}
body{
    background: #eee;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color:#000;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.swiper-container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.swiper-slide{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    background: #eee;
    /* Center slide text vertically */
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
}
.swiper-pagination-bullet{
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color:#000;
    opacity: 1;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    font-weight: bold;
}
.swiper-pagination-bullet-active{
    color: #000;
    background: #007aff;
}
```

Kindly assist guys.

Answer (score 0):

add these lines before initializing your swiper:

```
const swiper = this.swiper;
swiper.loopDestroy();
swiper.loopCreate();
```

For example

```
const swiper = this.swiper;
swiper.loopDestroy();
swiper.loopCreate();

var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', { 
    slidesPerView: 'auto',
    pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
        clickable: true,
    },
});
```